# Declaring a struct for json objects

Tags: json, go, struct

I have a JSON response object from a API like that:

```
[
    {
        "peoples": {
            "1": {"name": "Jhon", "age": 123},
            "2": {"name": "Jhon", "age": 123},
            "3": {"name": "Jhon", "age": 123},
            "4": {"name": "Jhon", "age": 123},
            "_object": true,
            "_timestamp": "2020-08-05T07:05:55.509Z",
            "_writable": false
        }
    }
]
```

The parameters: `peoples`, `_object`, `_timestamp` and `_writable` is fixed. The dynamic values are the `1,2,3,4...n` parameters.

The qty of `peoples` in that struct can be more then 4 or can be 1. Have any elegant solution for create a Struct object or a `json.Unmarshal` for that?

Comment: The usual method is to unmarshal into `map[string]interface{}` or `map[string]json.RawMessage` (which to use depends on what you'll do with the results; raw message requires a second unmarshal but that can be convenient).

Comment: It is not trivial, here is an example that you can follow https://play.golang.org/p/pgdy_9MOAbn

Comment: That's the exactly I need to work well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please insert a answer for I accept? Probably this will help someone in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing [the input example from Sarath Sadasivan Pillai](https://play.golang.org/p/pgdy_9MOAbn) (see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63401590/declaring-a-struct-for-json-objects#comment112111098_63401590)), [here (link to Playground example)](https://play.golang.org/p/sdn1n5DdDNs) is a way to do it with `map[string]json.RawMessage` and a custom unmarshal function:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
}

type Keywords struct {
    Object    bool      `json:"_object"`
    Timestamp time.Time `json:"_timestamp"`
    Writable  bool      `json:"_writable"`
}

type Decoded struct {
    People map[string]Person // or perhaps just []Person
    Info   Keywords
}

var input []byte = []byte(`{
        "1": {"name": "Jhon", "age": 123},
        "2": {"name": "Jhon", "age": 123},
        "3": {"name": "Jhon", "age": 123},
        "4": {"name": "Jhon", "age": 123},
        "_object": true,
        "_timestamp": "2020-08-05T07:05:55.509Z",
        "_writable": false
}`)

// Unmarshal json in the input format outlined by
// the example above: a map of numeric strings to Name/Age pair,
// plus some keywords.

func (d *Decoded) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &d.Info); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    var m map[string]json.RawMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &m); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if d.People == nil {
        d.People = make(map[string]Person)
    }
    for k := range m {
        // This is the hard part: you must choose how
        // to decide whether to decode this as a Person.
        // Here, we use strconv.Atoi() as in the example
        // by Sarath Sadasivan Pillai, but there are as
        // many options as you can think of.
        //
        // For instance, another method would be to try
        // decoding the json.RawMessage as a Person.  It's
        // also not clear whether the numeric values imply
        // some particular ordering, which maps discard.
        // (If these come out in order, that's just luck.)
        if _, err := strconv.Atoi(k); err != nil {
            continue
        }
        var p Person
        if err := json.Unmarshal(m[k], &p); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        d.People[k] = p
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var x Decoded
    err := json.Unmarshal(input, &x)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("failed: %v\n", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("succeeded:\n%#v\n", x.Info)
        for k := range x.People {
            fmt.Printf("person %q = %#v\n", k, x.People[k])
        }
    }
}
```